# My button can't open my class

Tags: java, button, constructor, fxml

Basically, the problem is I created an interface with Java Scene Builder. And from FXML button I wanted to open my class.

```
    @FXML
    public void pressButton(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        try{
            new SerialChart().start(new Stage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    }

    @FXML
    public void pressButton2(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {                      
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
         try {
            new Main().start(new Stage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    }
```

And my Main can be open, but my SerialChart can't be opened. It says "The constructor SerialChart() is undefined". So here is the problem I think

```
    public SerialChart(String title) {  
    super(title);
```

I think this is the problem why I can't open. Please help me... I can show you the whole code if you need.

Comment: In order to invoke `new SerialChart()` you have to have a constructor defined that takes no arguments.  You have not shown the code for `SerialChart` so it's impossible for anyone to help you.  If the constructor you show is the only one defined, that explains the error.

Comment: @JimGarrison Can you help me? how to contact you? my sincere

Comment: If none of the solutions works for you and it is probable that this needs some time to solve, why don't you use it to create a simplified example of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Like Jim Garrisson said, your constructor that you call takes no arguments, but your defined one does (String title). This means you need to pass in a String argument (Even a blank one like "" will work) when you call it in the Button function.

```
new SerialChart("Some Title").start(new Stage()); //should be your call in the Button function.
```

Answer (score 0):

so this is the answer I figured out SO HAPPY

```
    public void pressButton(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        try{
            SerialChart serialChartDemo = new SerialChart("Clean Energy Data Real time graph");
            serialChartDemo.pack();  
            RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(serialChartDemo);  
            serialChartDemo.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}
```